# Does win32 std::thread leak memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-leaks

I compiled the following code with MinGW gcc 4.8.2 under Windows 7 32-bit:

```
// t.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class Mine
{
public:
    Mine() { std::cout << "Ctor called\n"; }
    ~Mine() { std::cout << "Dtor called\n"; }
};

void foo(const Mine &a, const Mine &s)
{
}

int main()
{
    Mine a, b;
    std::thread t(&foo, std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

with `g++ t.cpp -std=c++11 -static -ggdb`, and debug it using Dr. Memory with `drmemory a.exe`, and I got the following output:

```
Dr. Memory version 1.6.1739 build 42 built on Feb 23 2014 22:29:25
Dr. Memory results for pid 7400: "a.exe"
Application cmdline: "a.exe"
Recorded 102 suppression(s) from default C:\Users\apple\Desktop\drmemory\bin\suppress-default.txt

Error #1: LEAK 32 direct bytes 0x00d70e70-0x00d70e90 + 32 indirect bytes
# 0 replace_calloc                      [e:\b\build\slave\win-builder\drmemory\common\alloc_replace.c:2338]
# 1 pthread_spin_init                   [C:\Users\apple\Desktop/t.cpp:22]
# 2 static_spin_init                    [C:\Users\apple\Desktop/t.cpp:22]
# 3 pthread_getspecific                 [C:\Users\apple\Desktop/t.cpp:22]
# 4 _Unwind_SjLj_Register               [C:\mingw482\i686-482-posix-sjlj-rt_v3-r2\build\gcc-4.8.2\i686-w64-mingw32\libgcc/./gthr-default.h:719]
# 5 msvcrt.dll!_endthreadex
# 6 msvcrt.dll!_endthreadex
# 7 KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk   +0x11     (0x77021174 <KERNEL32.dll+0x51174>)

===========================================================================
FINAL SUMMARY:

DUPLICATE ERROR COUNTS:

SUPPRESSIONS USED:

ERRORS FOUND:
      0 unique,     0 total unaddressable access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total uninitialized access(es)
      0 unique,     0 total invalid heap argument(s)
      0 unique,     0 total GDI usage error(s)
      0 unique,     0 total warning(s)
      1 unique,     1 total,     64 byte(s) of leak(s)
      0 unique,     0 total,      0 byte(s) of possible leak(s)
ERRORS IGNORED:
     28 unique,    28 total,   1215 byte(s) of still-reachable allocation(s)
         (re-run with "-show_reachable" for details)
Details: C:\Users\apple\Desktop\drmemory\drmemory\logs\DrMemory-a.exe.7400.000\results.txt
```

The output of a.exe itself is (correctly) "Ctor called" * 2 and "Dtor called" * 2. I couldn't see anything that could cause a leak.

P.S. I've tried both dwarf2 and sjlj versions of mingw-gcc 4.8.2, both of which produced the same result.

P.P.S. I just tried boost thread library, with still the similar result. I'd really appreciate it if anyone can try it with MSVC.

Comment: For what it's worth, I compiled the same code with g++ 4.8.2 on Linux. Valgrind reported "All heap blocks were freed, no leaks possible", so either it's a bug that's been fixed in newer libstdc++, or it's the underlying Windows thread implementation that's leaking

Comment: @TristanBrindle I see. Is it possible for you to try it with msvc? I don't have it installed on my computer.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have a Windows machine available

Comment: Some implementations do deliberately leak some small, constant stuff to avoid bothering to clean it up on program end, when this would be potentially problematic or difficult. This is especially the case for vendor-specific OS APIs, because assumptions can be made about the encapsulating environment: in this instance, it may just be Microsoft using their knowledge that this particular resource _will_ be nuked by process destruction, to not bother. It does kind of confuse matters when you try to find real leaks, though.

Comment: Try create a few thousand threads and see if the leaked memory increases. It's not that uncommon for a runtime to allocate some memory on startup (that it never frees, since memory is free'd on exit anyway). The only drawback is that memory leak detectors might report false positives.

Comment: Reachable memory that is deallocated upon process close is not a leak.

Comment: Had to move to using __beginthreadex on windows until the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically [**`–ignore_early_leaks`**](http://www.drmemory.org/docs/page_options.html) will help, otherwise if you can prove that this is indeed not a leak (and it doesn't look so) - as suggested in the comments, you will need to otherwise [**`-suppress`**](http://www.drmemory.org/docs/page_options.html) these errors in your application. See suppression format examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, but with `-ignore_early_leaks` Dr. Memory still detects so-called leaks. Anyway, I guess they aren't real leaks.